How a function could identify the type of working context, without specify it with a new parameter, keeping the existing function call syntax
The situation is the next:

A function func1() needs to be adapted to consider a previously unconsidered type of working case. So, after the new changes the function will have a total of 2 types of working cases, case_A (current) and case_B (new).

There is a set of working scripts already having a specific function call syntax for func1(), and for that reason and other requirements, the part about the function call syntax can't be modified, which means that in this situation it isn't a solution adding another new parameter in func1() to specify the type of working case, because it would modify the existing instructions that make the function calls, i.e. that if already using func1(array_1, param_2) then it would not be a solution to now use something as func1(array_1, param_2, case_type).

So, the goal is to find a way to identify the type of working case, but without adding new parameters to the function, and to achieve that, of course the function logic will need to be modified.


case_A:
The function works with all values of a received array.
case_B:
The function only works with the first index value of a received array.
Reason to have 2 types of cases:
More efficient processing and less memory usage when only is needed the calculation for 1 single value in the array.

Possible solutions already considered at the moment to post this question:

Another parameter with default value. This would be a half solution because it keeps the same call syntax only for one of the 2 types of cases. A clarification here is that there won't be "new" code for calls, and that is because both types of working cases already exist, so the key is to find a way to make one of them more efficient (when only working with the first index value of the array).

Using the length of the received array to identify type of case. The problem with this is that the array length can vary significantly in both types of cases, so it would only work for some specific situations.

Also, it has been considered to append a kind of final "special" numeric value to the array before sending it to the function, doing this is the first steps in the program workflow. This, for the case_B situations, but this option hasn't been chosen in order to not to have to modify the received array in any way.

The initial idea (just as brainstorming) was the function could identify the type of working case with the variable name given to one of the arguments in the call. As idea on paper, this would be a possible solution, but it seems that a python function can't "see" the string variable name used in the call:
How to get a function call argument string name, inside the same function. Using that as "extra parameter", avoiding adding an extra parameter


import numpy as np

#...

def func1(array1, param2):
    '''
    # The content of this multi-line comment is just an illustrative idea, anything else.

    if argument_var_name == format_X:
        # case = case_A
    elif argument_var_name == format_Y:
        # case = case_B
    '''
    
    len_array = len(array1)
    func_array = np.zeros(len_array)

    for i in range(len_array):
        func_array[i] = array1[i] * param2
    
    return func_array


array_1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
param_2 = 2

func1_call = func1(array_1, param_2)

print(f'func1_call: {func1_call}')

As you can see, I've been trying to find a way where the function could identify the type of working case with some kind of aspect that is present outside the function, in order to modify the function logic to make the identification, so I hope that other programmers with experience with similar situations can share other ways to handle this in an efficient way.
Thank you in advance
UPDATE 1:
I really don't understand the reason to give negative votes to the question. Possibly most of us perfectly know how to "solve" this with just adding a new parameter in the function to manually provide the type of working case, but if that had been a valid solution, there would be no need to open the thread. So, the point with this question has been just to look for other alternative ways to identify a working context.

"it keeps the same call syntax only for one of the two cases" - does that matter? You should be changing the cases where the new behaviour is being switched to.

You should design your program to use types (i.e. classes) that give you the information you need. So instead of passing in an int, let's say in the caller you have variable1 = 42, you actually want some more complex types, e.g. in ths case, a tuple (but it could be a custom class, and probably should be) variable1 = (42, "variable1") and that is passed to param1.

The key idea here: variable names are for people reading/writing code to understand the program. Don't put data in variable names. Data that is actually used by the program should be explicitly provided.

Why can't you add an optional parameter (with default=None) that you will be populating only in new calls? Old calls would not need to be updated.

Add parameter iscase2=False this will not change the required parameters that already exist

Why do you need the same call syntax for the new case? Since your code evidently is currently using the first, existing case only, why is there a requirement for something you have not used yet? I don't understand this requirement. I don't see why the optional argument solution would not work for you.  You write "This would be a half solution because it keeps the same call syntax only for one of the two cases.". Why "half" when the only type of call you have currently is of the first type. Any new code using the second case can pass two arguments. I don't see the problem.

@PM77-1, that was one of the considered possible solution, but actually, what will be new is just the function case, not the function call, in this case it won't be "new calls" and that was the reason to discard that option.

@juanpa.arrivillaga, what you mention about to use a tuple instead of an 'int' would requiere to modify the existing call syntax, but it is an alternative. Btw, I just wanted to list each possible solution considered, just as brainstorming but not necessarily as a serious consideration. Thank you

@trincot, please read the comment to PM77-1. In this case it won't be "new calls", those calls are already existing, and the goal is to make them more efficient and not to make calculations for a whole array where only is needed 1 value calculation. The call syntax needs to be same as the previous, it is a requirement and that's the reason because the question is not focused into modify the syntax (adding more parameters) and instead of that to find another kind of way to achieve the same result as if adding that other parameter.

@jonrsharpe, yes it matters, and keeping the same existing syntax is the whole purpose for this thread. If not, it wouldn't be a reason to open the thread. Please read the comments responses with more extra information.

@JonSG, please read the updated here in the comment section. In this case the code for the function call is already done and working. The purpose is to keep all the call syntax but making more efficient that kind of existing process that need calculation only for 1 array element and not for the whole array.

@codev the point isn't to use a tuple, as I said, the point is to use some composite type. but it isn't clear what you mean by changing the call syntax in this case, the call syntax would be exactly he same, the logic in the function would have to change though.

Hello, codev, You could put your method inside a class, which has an attribute onlyOne = False when you need to process only one item, you use the setOnlyOne() method (which sets onlyOne to True), and when the execution is finished, it returns to the original value.

@juanpa.arrivillaga, about to keep the existing call syntax (the existing working code outside the function), it just means that if already using func1(array_1, param_2), then it would not be a solution to now use something as func1(array_1, param_2, case_type) because the purpose of the thread is precisely to avoid changes in those parts about the function call. And yes, in this case is the logic in the function that needs to change because the goal is the function can identify the type of case. So, looking for a way to identify the type of case without the need to add an extra parameter.

@codev you seem to be misunderstanding what I mean with y example, the call wouldn't change, it's the type of object you are passing in that would change. it would still be func1(x, y), there would still be precisely two positional parameters

@juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for your fast responses. Could you please provide an example? because about what you mentioned in your first comment, I understand that it would keep without changes the part of func1(array_1, param_2), but I see it would require to modify all the existing instructions that give the value to param_2, right? Btw, the question has been updated with more clarifications.
